# Автозапуск приложения на андроиде

Tags: android, android-studio

Не могу понять как работает автозапуск приложения вот мой код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    package="com.example.loginpage">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.loginpage.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/tobo_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".login">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".loading">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <receiver android:name="com.example.loginpage.MyBroadcastReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                    <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    </application>


</manifest
```

здесь вроде бы все правильно, а вот что делать с вот этим

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
        Log.d("Cre","working");
    }
```

вроде бы все правильно, но все же неработает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы поместили объявление провайдера внутрь тега активити. Это неправильно. Провайдер должен быть объявлен внутри тэга `application`

Comment: Спасибо все работает

Comment: а как сделать чтобы это приложение открывалось в background когда происходит автозапуск? У меня когда запускается я его вижу в открытых приложениях и могу его закрыть, как сделать чтоб его не было видно @ЮрийСПб

Comment: @Sergey, попробуйте это отдельным вопросом задать. Лично я ответа не знаю и даже сомневаюсь что это возможно безо всяких манипуляций с рутованием девайса и прочими хаками

Comment: возможно я неправильно выразился, вот например приложение "вконтакте" оно начинает работать сразу как включается телефон, и пресылает тебе оповещения даже если ты в него не заходил и ты не видишь его в запущенных @ЮрийСПб

Comment: можете пожалуйста посмотреть на этот вопрос может вы знаете ответ     https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654824/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-cookie-%D0%BD%D0%B0-iosocket

Comment: @Sergey, ВК скорее всего использует пуши. Они, могу за Firebase говорить, обрабатываются сервисами гугла, т.е. это они запущены, не приложение. Но это совсем иная реализация уведомлений и работы с ними. А про второй вопрос я ничего не знаю)

Comment: Спасибо! Если вам не сложно можете посмотреть еще вот этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655100/push-notification-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4

Comment: В сокеты я не умею и про неубиваемые сервисы знаю лишь что это невозможно без рута

Comment: Нет, спасибо, в чаты я не хожу)