# FirebaseCloudMessading андроид

Tags: android, firebase-android, firebase

есть socket

```
public static Socket socket;{
        try{
            socket = IO.socket("http://www.my.socket:3080/");
        }catch (URISyntaxException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

socket.connect();
        socket.on("broadcast", handleIncomingMessages);
```

когда приходит сообщение с socketa должно выводится уведомление

```
private Emitter.Listener handleIncomingMessages = new Emitter.Listener(){
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args){
            String message;

            message = (String) args[0];
            Log.d("message", message);
            if (message!=null){
                Context context = getApplicationContext();

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                        0, notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                Resources res = context.getResources();
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.action)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.action))
                        .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.warning)) 
                        .setTicker("News")
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                       .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notifytitle))
                        .setContentTitle("News")
                        .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notifytext))
                        .setContentText("You have news ");    
                Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
                Notification notification = builder.build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);

            }
        }

    };
```

все работает при включенном приложении, даже если его свернуть все работает, но если закрыть приложение оповещение не приходит. Как это можно преобразовать в FCM. Заранее спасибо!!!!

Comment: Закрылось приложение, закроется и сокет. Более того, пока оно открыто, оно будет активно потреблять батарею. Держать соединение постоянно открытым - это плохая практика.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ммм понятно, можно какой нибудь совет?

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед и используйте [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).